# creating a calendar in AVD

Tags: android, calendar, android-virtual-device

I'm writing a small android app to make some updates to the calendar. I'm using the AVD to test it. But in the AVD calendar app I don't see any existing calendar account (without which I can't insert any event). When I try to click on "Add Account" nothing happens and I see the following logs in the log cat. Could someone please help me to create a calendar account?

```
com.android.settings.accounts.ChooseAccountActivity; instances=2; limit=1
03-21 11:20:12.982: E/StrictMode(506): android.os.StrictMode$InstanceCountViolation: class com.android.settings.accounts.ChooseAccountActivity; instances=2; limit=1
03-21 11:20:12.982: E/StrictMode(506):  at android.os.StrictMode.setClassInstanceLimit(StrictMode.java:1)
```

Comment: OK, I have partially solved the problem. In the AVD manager I played around with the target API and I needed to chose "Google APIs" instead of the Android SDK. I am not too sure about the difference though. This lets me create an account but not a calendar yet.